# python script to concatenate values by row and delete identical

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

I am using python 2.7, and I have a text file that looks like this:

```
id     value
---    ----
1      x
2      a
1      z
1      y
2      b
```

I am trying to get an ouput that looks like this:

```
id     value
---    ----
1      x,z,y
2      a,b
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: I rolled back your question because it non-trivially changed the question and invalidated all answers. Please ask a new question instead of doing such kinds of edits. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#read
fp=open('','r') 
d=fp.read().split("\n")
fp.close()
x=len(d)
for i in range(len(d)):
    n= d[i].split()
    d.append(n)
d=d[x:]
```

---

```
m={}
for i in d:
    if i[0] not in m:
        m[i[0]]=[i[1]]
    else:
        if i[1] not in m[i[0]]:
            m[i[0]].append(i[1])
for i in m:
    print i,",".join(m[i])
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). If you don't care about order you could also use `set`s instead of `OrderedDict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict

# Keeps all unique values for each id
dd = defaultdict(OrderedDict)
# Keeps the unique ids in order of appearance
ids = OrderedDict()

with open(yourfilename) as f:
    f = iter(f)
    # skip first two lines
    next(f), next(f)  
    for line in f:
        id_, value = list(filter(bool, line.split()))  # split at whitespace and remove empty ones
        dd[id_][value] = None  # dicts need a value, but here it doesn't matter which one...
        ids[id_] = None

print('id     value')
print('---    ----')
for id_ in ids:
    print('{}      {}'.format(id_, ','.join(dd[id_])))
```

Result:

```
id     value
---    ----
1      x,z,y
2      a,b
```

In case you want to write it to another file just concatenate what I printed with `\n` and `write` it to a file.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could also work, although the other answer seems more sophisticated:

```
input =['1,x',
'2,a',
'1,z',
'1,y',
'2,b',
'2,a', #added extra values to show duplicates won't be added
'1,z',
'1,y']

output = {}

for row in input:
    parts = row.split(",")
    id_ = parts[0]
    value = parts[1]
    if id_ not in output:
        output[id_] = value
    else:
        a_List = list(output[id_])
        if value not in a_List:
            output[id_] += "," + value
        else:
            pass
```

You end up with a dictionary similar to what you requested.

Comment: Just a minor thing: `id` will shadow the builtin `id` function. Better to give it a different name, i.e. `id_`. Good solution otherwise (+1)

Comment: Please note, though, that there are no commas in the value strings using this method... if anyone wants to chime in on how to change this, I'd be interested.

Comment: You could use `output[id_] += ',' + value` (instead of `output[id_] += value`) if you want to insert the commas.

Comment: Note that your solution might produce unexpected result (at least the duplicate check won't work correctly all the time) for multi-character values, e.g. if you add `'1,zab'` at the beginning of the list (or `'2,ab'`).

Comment: Yes, the solution would be to use a container that throws away duplicates (i.e. `set`, `dict` or `OrderedDict`) as value in the `output` dictionary instead of a string and only join/concatenate the values afterwards.